# Jquery slide left and right through unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, slide

[image]

I'm currently developing the UI/UX search filter interface that's apart of much bigger web app.

I have everything working, but I want to clean up the code, specifically the jQuery slide left and right effect via animation. (See screenshot)

Libraries and Frameworks being used:

- Kendo UI
- JQuery
- Foundation 6

CodePen: http://codepen.io/covanant/pen/rxNBvN/

JQuery UI is not allowed in this project which is why I'm using animation to create the same effect as "slide" in jQuery UI.

Below is the code I'm using to slide through each popup.

**Next**

```
  $("#nextButton1").click(function() {
    var $lefty = $("#popUp1");
    $lefty.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0      
    }).delay(400).fadeOut("fast");    
    var $lefty2 = $("#popUp2");

    $lefty2.animate({
      left: parseInt($lefty2.css({left: $lefty2.outerWidth(), display: 'block' }), 10) == 0 ?
        -$lefty2.outerWidth()  :  0  
    });        
  });
```

**Last**

```
  $("#lastButton2").click(function() {
    var $righty = $("#popUp2");
    $righty.animate({
      left: parseInt($righty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ?
        $righty.outerWidth() : 0      
    }).delay(400).fadeOut("fast");    
    var $righty2 = $("#popUp1");

    $righty2.animate({
      left: parseInt($righty2.css({left: -$righty2.outerWidth(), display: 'block' }), 10) == 0 ?
        -$righty2.outerWidth()  :  0  
    });        
  });
```

It's a modified snippet from [Learning jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions), I'm sure some parts of it aren't even necessary. Basically I repeat this snippet for each popup, I know it's horrible but that's the extent of my JS capabilities.

The problem is, there will be other scenarios when there will be much more pop ups.

I need some help making this "slide left and right" effect more elegant and compact.

Thank you.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/covanant/pen/rxNBvN/